# How to implement Spring Rest Client for elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

We are developing an elastic search application in spring boot. We cannot use the Java API or Java Rest Client API's provided by the elastic search. Instead, we need to do operations in elastic using spring rest template, but elastic doesn't seem to be accepting index requests from the rest client.We got "Not Acceptable" response back. I really appreciate if anyone gives us some hints or information.

elastic version: 5.6

Comment: Please show the code you have now. And with ES 5.6 you can use the [low-level REST client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-low-usage-initialization.html) which is simply a wrapper around Apache's HTTP client without any other dependencies.

Comment: Most probably you're not sending the `Content-Type` header in your HTTP request headers. Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me for Indexing Document through HTTP API using HttpURLConnection.

```
URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:9200/index/type");
String json = "{\n" + 
            "    \"user\" : \"kimchy\",\n" + 
            "    \"post_date\" : \"2009-11-15T14:12:12\",\n" + 
            "    \"message\" : \"trying out Elasticsearch\"\n" + 
            "}";
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
osw.write(json);
osw.flush();
osw.close();

System.out.println(con.getResponseCode() + " : " + con.getResponseMessage());
if (con != null)
    con.disconnect();
```

Doing a simple search using HttpURLConnection.

```
URL obj = new URL("http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search");
String json = "{\n" + 
                "  \"query\": {\n" + 
                "    \"match_all\": {}\n" + 
                "  }\n" + 
                "}";
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setDoInput(true);
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
osw.write(json);
osw.flush();
osw.close();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));

System.out.println("Response : " + br.readLine());

System.out.println(con.getResponseCode() + " : " + con.getResponseMessage());

if (con != null)
    con.disconnect();
```

Comment: Can you show an example of doing a search with a simple request body?

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope that helps.